# Expected value of $X + Z^2$ with respect to $Z$ when $Z = X + Y$

Tags: measure-theory, expected-value

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $f(X, Y) = X + (X+Y)^2 = X + Z^2$, where $Z = X + Y$

Can we find the expected value of $f(X, Y)$ with respect to $Z$?

Comment: What does 'w.r.t. $Z$' mean?

Comment: With respect to the random variable $Z$.

Comment: That is not a standard terminology. Are you asking for $E(f(X,Y))|Z)$?

Comment: Actually, this has been written in a paper which I can't share with. It states that it is taking the expectation of f(X, Y) with respect to Z and has written it as $X + E[Z^2]$ (treating it as two random variables X and Z (has not considered that Z = X + Y)). But I am thinking whether it should be E[f(X, Y) | X]. That's why I am asking whether "Can we find the expectation of f(X, Y) with respect to Z"?.